# Split array of objects with different properties names into an object and separate them by a given name

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing objects. Now I want to slice the array to a new object containing only those objects matching a certain property name and grouped by this property name. The thing is that I also have properties names that are different between them. The names and ID's repeat through the array of objects, but inside the new object, it should contain the ID and the name only once.

The original array looks like this:

```
let personArray = [
    {
        id_dentist: 1,
        dentist_name: 'John',
        id_secretary: 6,
        secretary_name: 'Paul',
        id_security: 3,
        security_name: 'Carl'
    },
    {
        id_dentist: 2,
        dentist_name: 'Lisa',
        id_secretary: 9,
        secretary_name: 'Beth',
        id_security: 5,
        security_name: 'Monica'
    },
    {
        id_dentist: 1,
        dentist_name: 'John',
        id_secretary: 6,
        secretary_name: 'Paul',
        id_security: 3,
        security_name: 'Carl'
    }
];
```

The new object should look like this:

```
let personObject = {
    dentist: [
        { id_dentist: 1, dentist_name: 'John' },
        { id_dentist: 2, dentist_name: 'Lisa' },
    ],
    secretary: [
        { id_secretary: 6, secretary_name: 'Paul' },
        { id_secretary: 9, secreatary_name: 'Beth' },
    ],
    security: [
        { id_security: 3, security_name: 'Carl' },
        { id_security: 5, security_name: 'Monica' }
    ]
};
```

I appreciate the help.

As requested, I tried using `reduce()` and `filter()`, but I was not able to make them to split.
Here is the code:

```
const obj = personArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const key = Object.keys(cur).filter(f => /^id_/.test(f))[0].split('_')[1];
    if (!acc[key]) acc[key] = [];
    acc[key].push(cur);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

About the strange data structure, I am getting those data from a database with a `SELECT` SQL syntax.

Comment: This seems like a very strange data structure. Why are all these different jobs mixed into the same objects?

Comment: I updated the question to fit your criteria. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It will almost certainly be easier if you use ordinary `for` loops. Once you get that working, you can try to refactor it into `reduce`.

Comment: That was my first approach, but still I could not make it work. I guess I will just keep trying. I appreciate your time replying.

Comment: `key` is an array. You're never looping over it to find the `XXX_name` properties that should be combined with `id_XXX`.

Comment: Do you want to use vanilla JS for it or are u willing to use a library like underscore?

Comment: @NavalRishi It really doesn't matter, as long as I am able to get the result expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, This can be enhance further

```js
let personArray = [{"id_dentist":1,"dentist_name":"John","id_secretary":6,"secretary_name":"Paul","id_security":3,"security_name":"Carl"},{"id_dentist":2,"dentist_name":"Lisa","id_secretary":9,"secretary_name":"Beth","id_security":5,"security_name":"Monica"},{"id_dentist":1,"dentist_name":"John","id_secretary":6,"secretary_name":"Paul","id_security":3,"security_name":"Carl"}];

const personObject = { dentist: [], secretary: [], security: [] };
const isExist = (arr, id, key) => arr.find(x => x[key] === id);


personArray.reduce((personObj, person) => {
  
  const isDentistExists = isExist(personObj.dentist, person.id_dentist, 'id_dentist');
  
  if (!isDentistExists) {
    personObj.dentist.push({
      id_dentist: person.id_dentist,
      dentist_name: person.dentist_name
    });
  }
  
  const isSecretaryExists = isExist(personObj.secretary, person.id_secretary, 'id_secretary');
  
  if (!isSecretaryExists) {
    personObj.secretary.push({
      id_secretary: person.id_secretary,
      secretary_name: person.secretary_name
    });
  }
  
  const isSecurityExists = isExist(personObj.security, person.id_security, 'id_security');
  
  if (!isSecurityExists) {
    personObj.security.push({
      id_security: person.id_security,
      security_name: person.security_name
    });
  }
  
  return personObj;
}, personObject);

console.log(personObject);
```

Comment: though pretty basic and straightforward, I'd say it does the job so it's worth picking up.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a trivial algorithm. Here is a [mostly] functional implementation that handles an arbitrary number of ids and names

```js
let personArray = [
  {
    id_dentist: 1,
    dentist_name: 'John',
    id_secretary: 6,
    secretary_name: 'Paul',
    id_security: 3,
    security_name: 'Carl',
  },
  {
    id_dentist: 2,
    dentist_name: 'Lisa',
    id_secretary: 9,
    secretary_name: 'Beth',
    id_security: 5,
    security_name: 'Monica',
  },
  {
    id_dentist: 1,
    dentist_name: 'John',
    id_secretary: 6,
    secretary_name: 'Paul',
    id_security: 3,
    security_name: 'Carl',
  },
]

const parsed = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.keys(personArray[0])
    .filter(key => key.startsWith('id_'))
    .map(id => {
      const uniqIds = [...new Set(personArray.map(person => person[id]))]
      const [, name] = id.split('_')
      const matchingPeople = uniqIds.map(uniqId => {
        return personArray.find(person => uniqId === person[id])
      })
      return matchingPeople.map(person => ({
        [id]: person[id],
        [`${name}_name`]: person[`${name}_name`],
      }))
    })
    .filter(entry => entry.length > 0)
    .map(groupedPeople => {
      const [name] = Object.keys(groupedPeople[0])
        .find(key => key.includes('_name'))
        .split('_')
      return [name, groupedPeople]
    })
)
console.log(parsed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably went along a similar path as @Andrew did and, yes, I admit too, that this was not really trivial.

It might be a better idea to change your SQL selection in order to avoid receiving redundant data that makes these lengthy conversions necessary.

```js
const arr = [
{
    id_dentist: 1,
    dentist_name: 'John',
    id_secretary: 6,
    secretary_name: 'Paul',
    id_security: 3,
    security_name: 'Carl'
},
{
    id_dentist: 2,
    dentist_name: 'Lisa',
    id_secretary: 9,
    secretary_name: 'Beth',
    id_security: 5,
    security_name: 'Monica'
},
{
    id_dentist: 1,
    dentist_name: 'John',
    id_secretary: 6,
    secretary_name: 'Paul',
    id_security: 3,
    security_name: 'Carl'
}
], types=Object.keys(arr[0]).reduce((a,c,k)=>{
 k=c.match(/id_(.*)/);
 if(k) a.push(k[1]);
 return a;
},[]);

const res=Object.entries(arr.reduce((a,c)=>{
 types.forEach((t,id)=>{
  id="id_"+t;
  a[t+":"+c[id]]={[id]:c[id],[t+"_name"]:c[t+"_name"]}
 });
 return a;
},{})).reduce((a,[k,o],n)=>{
 [n]=k.split(":");
 (a[n]=a[n]||[]).push(o)
 return a;
},{});

console.log(res);
```